# Can you play a texture atlas in reverse in spritekit?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, sktextureatlas

I have a couple texture atlas' that I need to play normally under certain circumstances and then in reverse under different circumstance. These atlas's do not loop. They play once through and stop. I would prefer to not have to create additional texture atlas's just to play these animations in reverse.

TIA!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is just a basic question about the functionality of SKTextureAtlas'. There is no problem that I have with my code regarding this. Couldn't find documentation on this topic.